# Cannot query iis log by LogPaser2.2

Tags: iis, logparser

I have set up a IIS server (.net appplication):

[image: IIS Settings]

I used logparser command:

`LogParser.exe -i:IIS select LogRow, date from xxx.log`

But exception occurs:

`Error while parsing field Date: Invalid Date value "12/14/2015": Invalid timestamp year digit '/' LogFile`
[image: IIS Query]

Since I need the date to handle some logic, anyone can help me with the issue like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you specify the locale of the Web server with the `-locale` argument. The default value for this argument is to use the current system's locale, but apparently your Web server is using a different locale than the system locale on the box where you're running Log Parser.